# How to remove several substring within a string in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab

I'm trying to implement in a different way what I can already do implementing some custom matlab functions. Let us suppose to have this string 'AAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTsssssssssssTTTTTTTTTT' I know to remove each lowercase sub strings with

```
regexprep(String, '[a-z]*', '')
```

But since I want to understand how to take indexes of these substrings and using them to check them and remove them maybe with a for loop I'm investigating about how to do it.
Regexp give the indexes :

```
 [Start,End] = regexp(Seq,'[a-z]{1,}');
```

but i'm not succeeding in figuring out how to use them to check these sequences and eliminate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the indexing approach you get several start and end indices (two in your example), so you need a **loop** to remove the corresponding sections from the string. You should remove them **from last to first**, otherwise indices that haven't been used yet will become invalid as you remove sections:

```
x = 'AAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTsssssssssssTTTTTTTTTT'; % input
y = x; % initiallize result
[Start, End] = regexp(x, '[a-z]{1,}');
for k = numel(Start):-1:1 % note: from last to first
    y(Start(k):End(k)) = []; % remove section
end
```